# Is it possible to use an operator as a mapped value in a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, operator-keyword

I want to do something like this:

```
int a = 9, b = 3;
map<char,operator> m;
m['+'] = +;
m['-'] = -;
m['*'] = *;
m['/'] = /;
for(map<char,operator>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
    cout << func(a,b,it -> second) << endl;
}
```

With the output being something like this:

```
12
6
27
3
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the premade functors in `<functional>`:

```
int a = 9, b = 3;
std::map<char, std::function<int(int, int)>> m;

m['+'] = std::plus<int>();
m['-'] = std::minus<int>();
m['*'] = std::multiplies<int>();
m['/'] = std::divides<int>();

for(std::map<char, std::function<int(int, int)>>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it->second(a, b) << std::endl;
}
```

Each one is a class with an `operator()` that takes two arguments and returns the result of a mathematical operation on those two arguments. For example, `std::plus<int>()(3, 4)` is basically the same as `3 + 4`. Each is stored as a function wrapper object of the signature `int(int, int)` and then called with the two numbers as needed.

Comment: You can't do that! There is no type `operator`. You cannot have `operator` as a template parameter.

Comment: @Jarryd, I just noticed that. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Yep that's better. You edited it just as I was writing that comment.

Comment: This is C++11, right? I am trying to compile it with G++ 4.3.2 and I'm getting errors.

Comment: @hinafu, Yes, `std::function` is C++11, as well as the `>>` in the template argument list.

Comment: Any way to do this in C++03 ?

Comment: @hinafu, Look into `boost::function`. As for the template issue, `std::map<char, boost::function<int(int, int)> >`. Putting in a space is enough to solve that issue. `boost::function` works approximately the same way as `std::function` as well.

Comment: I should have been clear from the start, I want to run this in an online judge and I don't think I can use boost there. Anyway, thanks for answering, I'm just looking for an standard method.

Comment: @hinafu: If you're forced to use C++03 without Boost, you could use an old-school function pointer, `std::map<char, int (*)(int,int)>` in this case. You'll need to write your own function for each operation.